# Should I get the Intuos Pro SMALL or LARGE?

Tags: drawing-tablet, wacom

My boyfriend is awesome and is going to be buying me one of those for Christmas this year. I have a macbook pro 13 inch mid 2014. I would like to use it to create digital art, digital drawing ect.

I want to make personal comic style, portraits, manga, I love water colors, paint, and use of colors. I like to draw people, nature, and animals. I'm not sure which I should use.

I've heard that the small is good if you prefer to zoom in for detail. I guess Im not sure. I wish there was a store that has them that would let you test them out but oh well.

I may call around but I figured I'd ask and see what you all think :) Thanks so much for the advice appreciated! Im not a newbie but Im not professional.

I havent use a pen tablet in a long time. I've never experimented with a medium sized one.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your drawing style.

Do a quick test. Grab a sheet of paper. Put it on the desk you normally work.

Draw happy, and I mean happy.

If you find drawing big strokes, with all your arm, you probably will be more confident with a large one.

If you find yourself only using your wrist, or even your fingers only, a small one.

The second test is the space. See your working space.

Tip: If you do not have problems with space, a large tablet can always reduce the sensitive area if one day you wake up and only your fingers are awake.

Comment: I second this: I use a 9x12" Intuos tablet, but after a while I started getting RSI from the large arm movements. I reduced the drawing area to a more comfortable size now; which is around 6x8", so I could have gotten the smaller tablet in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Iam happy owner of S size and after some 18 months of frequent use, I don't feel any urge to upgrade to medium. If I take closer look on scratches on the surface, I can tell that I've been using working space of size about 15x8cm (and zooming a lot, but thats what i do with mouse anyway), so it really is ONLY about your drawing style.